# Batch Scripting: Appending the name of a child directory to its parent

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am writing a portion of a script to append a child directory name to its parent. For example...

```
path/to/the/folders/2.2/...
```

I want to change to

```
path/to/the/folders.2.2/2.2/...
```

Right now I have the solution hard-coded with a number:

```
for /d %%a in (C:\path\to\the\folders\*) do move "%%a" "%%a.3.2"
```

which changes every folder in "folders" by adding a .3.2 postfix

Comment: You may want to look at the end of the FOR command's help. They are variable like %~dA which you can use to do things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 ECHO "%sourcedir%.%%a\%%a\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you - it's just showing the name generated by using `ECHO` - how you use it is up to you.

Your `path/to/the/folders.2.2/2.2/...` seems to differ from `path/to/the/folders.3.2` - in more ways than just the `/` (switch indicator) in place of `\` (directory separator)

Comment: Almost what I was looking for! I think there was a miscommunication about the structure of my path. I have five different source folders under my main directory and want to change the name of each of the five.

Comment: So that sourcedir has to iterate through each of the five directories UNDER \source